# How to specify a date on azcopy

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I am trying to use this wonderful tool [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy) to move blobs from one container to another container.
My problem is that I need to copy only the blobs that were modified during the past 40 days. Older blobs should not be copied.
Is there a parameter that I can specify to limit the data range?

Answer (score 4):

`azcopy` now has the `--include-after` flag (and `--include-before`).

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy):

> --include-after string Include only those files modified on or after the given date/time.

Answer (score 2):

You might can try to write your own program to copy the blobs bases on [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement). It's a library designed for high-performance transfer Blob/File.

You can refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement/blob/4b2918bdcb335657b8d427aadb581f89b8db9bed/samples/DataMovementSamples/DataMovementSamples/Samples.cs#L451) for how to copy a Blob Directory.
To copy only the blobs that were modified during the past 40 days, you can use DirectoryTransferContext.ShouldTransferCallbackAsync(), to decide if copy the each blob.

```
            context.ShouldTransferCallbackAsync = async (source, destination) =>
            {
                CloudBlob sourceBlob = source as CloudBlob;
                if (sourceBlob != null)
                {
                    if (sourceBlob.Properties.LastModified >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-40))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            };
```

Comment: Does this mean that the blob transfer will have to go thru the client app?

Comment: When you call TransferManager.CopyDirectoryAsync(), if set "isServiceCopy" as true, the blob content will be copy on server side. Anyway, client will send the copy blob request, and check the blob copy status.

Answer (score 1):

There is no parameter (that I am aware of) that will do that.

One solution would be to write a program that enumerates all the files that have been changed in the last 40 days. Then use that program to generate an azcopy command for each blob to be copied.

You could use the code in this post as a starting point.

Comment: The problem is that there is about 200 Terabytes of blobs each at average of 10Kb.

Comment: What is the ratio of blobs before and after last 40 days?

Comment: The ratio is 1/12

Comment: The requested parameter has been logged as a feature request: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/716